# Matlab code to generate Nakagami fading channel

Tags: matlab, random, fading

I am doing some wireless communications simulations using Matlab. There are two famous channel models 1) Rayleigh fading and 2) Nakagami fading. I can easily generate Rayleigh fading which is a complex Gaussian random variable:

```
rayRv=(randn(1,1)+1i*randn(1,1))/sqrt(2)
```

Similarly, I want to generate Nakagami random variable but It makes me confuse as it is not a complex Gaussian but may be a sum of such variables (but I may have to carefully deal with the phase???). Many technical papers use Nakagami fading (say `nakRv`) but they mostly focus on `abs(nakRv)` which is easy to generate as we have clear distribution, or power version which is  `abs(nakRv)^2`, this can be generated with `gamma` distribution.

If anyone has experience of generating `nakRv` similar to `rayRv`, please share the code with me. Thanks !!!

Comment: Have no code, but did you have on hands Norman C. Beaulieu, and Christine Cheng "Efficient Nakagami-m Fading Channel Simulation"? I think it is all here...

Comment: I have seen such papers in IEEE but I could not come up with a clear way of generating the code.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to simulate `abs(nakRv)` first (and looks like you know how to do that) and just simulate random over `2 pi` phase and get the result as `abs(nakRv)*cos(phase) + i*abs(nakRv)*sin(phase)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`randraw`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7309-randraw) function to generate different distributions, including Nakagami-*m*, Rayleigh, Rice, etc.

You can use the following code line to draw a Nakagami distribution with a shape parameter of `m` and `n` random numbers:

```
h = randraw('nakagami', 1, [1,n]); % m=1 case of Rayleigh
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple manner to generate a Nakagami-m fading channel is to assume that its envelope follows Nakagami-m distribution, while its phase follows uniform.